# How to fix "socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

```
The anaconda causes the "socket.gaierror: \[Errno -5\] No address associated with hostname" error
```

The following code is referred to the https://colab.research.google.com/github/shreyagopal/Phishing-Website-Detection-by-Machine-Learning-Techniques/blob/master/URL%20Feature%20Extraction.ipynb#scrollTo=vABNo39RQljI

But when I run in my Ubuntu platform, the code cannot run successfully. Please help me.

````
```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# importing required packages for this section
from urllib.parse import urlparse,urlencode
import ipaddress
import re
import pandas as pd
import ssl

"""#### **3.1.1. Domain of the URL**
Here, we are just extracting the domain present in the URL. This feature doesn't have much significance in the training. May even be dropped while training the model.
"""

#!pip install python-whois

# importing required packages for this section
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import whois
import urllib
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime



# 12.Web traffic (Web_Traffic)
def web_traffic(url):
  try:
    #Filling the whitespaces in the URL if any
    url = urllib.parse.quote(url)
    rank = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=" + url).read(), "xml").find(
        "REACH")['RANK']
    rank = int(rank)
  except TypeError:
        return 1
  if rank <100000:
    return 1
  else:
    return 0


#converting the list to dataframe
url = "http://www.phishtank.com/phish_detail.php?phish_id=8127675"
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
except:
    response = ""

print(web_traffic(url))
````

```
The main program is as above, I get the following error:
hactl@hactl-ThinkPad-X201:~/Downloads/Phishing-Website-Detection-by-Machine-Learning-Techniques-master$ python testing.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 941, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 824, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hactl/Downloads/Phishing-Website-Detection-by-Machine-Learning-Techniques-master/testing.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(web_traffic(url))
  File "/home/hactl/Downloads/Phishing-Website-Detection-by-Machine-Learning-Techniques-master/testing.py", line 31, in web_traffic
    rank = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=" + url).read(), "xml").find(
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1377, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/home/hactl/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>

---------------------------------

I don't know how to fix this error.
```

Comment: please reduce your code to a minimal example that reproduces this error

Comment: I have reduced that code

Comment: Have you tried loading `http://data.alexa.com` in your browser?

Comment: Yes, the link is dead. You are right. Thanks for your help.